# Handling multiple instances of same fragment - android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Scenario :

I need to create tabs/with fragment, and populate views inside each fragments dynamically. Also user can navigate inside each fragment depending on the server response.

Now what I am trying to do is setting same fragment for all tabs and passing different model data according to the tab content. Its working. When i need to show a details page inside a tab again I am showing same fragment with new data. but it makes issues (view mix up) on other tabs since the container is same.

Can anyone suggest a flow by using single fragment for any new views and i need to pop it out from backstack also.